# jquery ajax boolean validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am doing this for a username validation, search for a name in DB through ajax, in `if` condition irrespective of the return value (true of false), I am getting an error message. That means it's taking only false. When I am debugging, ajax is working fine and it's taking the values of true or false according to situation and I am calling it as a normal jQuery validation with rules and messages. please help me out.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("shortNameCheck",function(value,element){

    if (value != null && value != "") {

        shortName = $('#shortName').val();
        $.ajax({ 
            dataType: 'json',
            url: clientsetup.props.shortNameValidation,
            data: "shortName=" + shortName + "&hierarchyNodeId=" + hirNodeId,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.shortNameCheck === 'true') {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: thnks for the reply,i tried both, its not working

Comment: try using `data.shortNameCheck.trim() == 'true'` to avoid any whitespaces

Comment: What does `alert(typeof data.shortNameCheck)` tell you?

Comment: thanks for the reply.from database it getting exactly  "true"..

Comment: thnks for the reply ishettyl. i m not getting any alert in if condition in success

Comment: Remove the `if/else` from success and just do `alert(typeof data.shortNameCheck)` for now.

Comment: alert is not working

Comment: That means it's not hitting the success block! Try putting an alert just before the ajax and after.

Comment: i did it, its not working anywhere

Answer (score 0):

use this --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bool = true;
console.log(typeof bool); // return boolean
if(bool === true)
    {
        alert('correct');
    }
</script>
```

change --

```
if (data.shortNameCheck === 'true')
```

To --

```
if (data.shortNameCheck === true)
```

Comment: thnks for the reply, i did it but its not working, alert is nor working.

Comment: you mean in my example alert('correct') is not working ??

Comment: in my code if (data.shortNameCheck === 'true') {
                    return false
                }  when i write alert in this box, its not comming, though i gave the name which is in db

Comment: i think you have to check your code i have a solution please do alert  data.shortNameCheck value what it return ??

Comment: again u are doing a mistake please remove single quote in true ....change --

if (data.shortNameCheck === 'true') 

To --

if (data.shortNameCheck === true)

Comment: its skipping alert.in tried all the points were the function is executing, in If>if and if>else,in the main function

Comment: can u tell me what its return  data.shortNameCheck

Comment: when i am in debugging mode, if it exits its gng in to if loop and if not else loop, and it says its returing true or false, no console or alert is working when i close the console

Comment: sorry i didn`t get can u make it on js fiddle ..??

Comment: bro, i m sorry i dnt know how to use it, all i have is the code which i displayed at the top and in the validation function i m setting this method to true and gave the errors. pls help me out

Comment: but how can i test it..i want to run your code please do google for js fiddle it will very helpful to you for future...

Comment: bro a small favor, can u pass ur own paraments in data and url and can u tell me whether the function body is working or not, so that i cant tell java developer to see it